# GIT Sourcetree existing files show up as new (case sensitive in windows)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

We have a repository issue where we are seeing files that exist already, showing up as un-tracked and not letting us reset the branch to the server state, they still show up. If we chose to remove them, they show up as removed and will actually remove the files.

Stashing the changes then makes the pending changes say we are removing the files. Stashing that change makes it go back to say we are adding the files. All which already exists, they are just showing up in a bad state.

We want to keep the files, but they are showing up as new and are not new, and other files keep entering this "state"

I have into the following, but nothing is helping thus far:

- the line endings (however that would present as a change not new)
- git.filemode
- https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/256544/why-is-sourcetree-showing-changes-when-there-are-none

seems to be we have folders on some machines as discounts and others as Discounts. Trying to rename creates more issues. I'm out of ideas other than removing the files and then renaming them to lower case.

Comment: So I deleted the folder, an then re-added with lowercase, also made sure all git config settings for core.ignorecase = true for global and system and local. We then pulled those changes down to the other branches. And then we had someone re-clone the repository, and its still showing up for them. Any more thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do not have SourceTree, but a few points that may help :

(1) Is the problem specific to SourceTree or does it happen in other clients - command line/GUI ?

(2) Does the repo actually has two files differing in just case in name ?

(3) How do the files's names appear on Linux ? Do they differ from what shows up in Windows in upper/lower case ? If so, one possible fix may be to rename the file on Linux to something completely new, push it to the repo and clone to a new working tree location on Windows.

Comment: The files are also showing up in Visual Studio, and sometimes they differ. I have tried to remove the entire folder structure and commit that, then add it back in as a lower case and then made sure all developers had lowercase and some are still popping up. I think our solution may be to just to clone down a new repo and just switch to that, hopefully resolving the issue if everyone does it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue multiple times, git being case sensitive and windows not. Every time we did a fetch it would replace Release with release and so on. Unfortunately, I too am yet to find an effective solution other than adding them manually. I had to add a a new folder on out GitLab instance and add files through that. Good luck! if you find a speedy way please message me.